# Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly

Tags: javascript, routes, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to set up routes and no components are showing which is due to this error I believe.

I have checked and there are no other router-view tags in the project, I have uninstalled vue-router and installed again, didn't fix the issue.

using
vue-router@2.2.0
vue@2.1.10

GIT: https://github.com/usmaanrazaq/App/

index.html
Where build.js is ommited

```html
<body>
  <div class='container-fluid background'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
        <div id="app">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="dist/build.js"></script>
```

main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);

import VueCookie from 'vue-cookie';
Vue.use(VueCookie);

import routes from '../routes/routes.js'
import app from '../src/App.vue';

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes
})


new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(app)
}).$mount('#app');
```

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  
}
</script>
```

routes.js

```js
import index from '../src/components/index.vue';
import home from '../src/components/home.vue';
import NotFoundView from '../src/components/notfound.vue';



const routes = [
  { path: '/login', component: index}, 
  { path: '/', component: home}, 
  { path: '*', component: NotFoundView }
]

export default routes
```

Comment: This looks right. Have a repo?

Comment: 45 mins later and here we go: https://github.com/usmaanrazaq/App/